# How can I Use from a variable instead of an amount for nu parameter in nu-SVM for libSVM in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, kernel, svm, libsvm

As you know, libSVM command is like this:

```
model_nu = svmtrain(train_classset, train_dataset,'-s 1 -t 0 -n 0.5'  );
```

and when I run it, it's OK.
But I need to use a variable instead of a number for nu. like this:

```
nu = 0.5;
 model_nu = svmtrain(train_classset, train_dataset,'-s 1 -t 0 -n nu'  );
```

When I do this, svmtrain function doesn't work.
So how can I use a variable instead of a number in svmtrain function of libSVM toolbox in Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the number into char:

```
model_nu = svmtrain(train_classset, train_dataset,sprintf('-s 1 -t 0 -n %f',nu))
```